# Unique within a column in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

From a dataframe like this

```
DF <- read.table(text = "String  Found   Count
                 0-025823    0    1   
                 1-042055    1    1   
                 1-018396    1    2   
                 1-018396    1    2   
                 1-002984    1    3   
                 1-002984    1    3   
                 1-002984    1    3", header = TRUE)
```

I would want to get the following output:

```
String  Found   Count   Desired output
0-025823    0    1       1
1-042055    1    1       1
1-018396    1    2       1
1-018396    1    2       0
1-002984    1    3       1
1-002984    1    3       0
1-002984    1    3       0
```

The `Desired output` column is showing the unique value starting from top to bottom. The very first unique value found will be tagged as 1 and rest (duplicates) will be all 0s.

I have used the following formula in excel to get the output in excel:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)>1,0,1)
where the sequenceof columns is same as above.
```

I have used loops, `aggregate` and `within` functions but these did not give the desired result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to mark duplicated values as 0:

```
DF <- read.table(text = "String  Found   Count
                 0-025823    0    1   
                 1-042055    1    1   
                 1-018396    1    2   
                 1-018396    1    2   
                 1-002984    1    3   
                 1-002984    1    3   
                 1-002984    1    3", header = TRUE)

DF$unique <- 1 - duplicated(DF$String)
#    String Found Count unique
#1 0-025823     0     1      1
#2 1-042055     1     1      1
#3 1-018396     1     2      1
#4 1-018396     1     2      0
#5 1-002984     1     3      1
#6 1-002984     1     3      0
#7 1-002984     1     3      0
```

`duplicated` returns logical values and I use that `TRUE`/`FALSE` is coerced to `1`/`0` when used in arithmetic.

Note that usually you should not coerce to integers. You could simply do `!duplicated(DF$String)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data frame is df

```
df[,"Desired output"]=0
for(i in (1:nrow(df)))
{
  if(length(which(df[1:i,]$Count==df[i,"Count"]))==1)
  {  df[i,"Desired output"]=1
  }
  else
  { 
     df[i,"Desired output"]=0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Roland's solution is faster than using `dplyr` but for the sake of presenting another solution:

```
 library(dplyr)
 DF %>% group_by(String) %>%  mutate(unique = ifelse(row_number()==1,1,0))

# # A tibble: 7 x 4 
# # Groups:   String [4] 
#     String Found Count unique 
#     <fctr> <int> <int>  <dbl> 
# 1 0-025823     0     1      1 
# 2 1-042055     1     1      1 
# 3 1-018396     1     2      1 
# 4 1-018396     1     2      0 
# 5 1-002984     1     3      1 
# 6 1-002984     1     3      0 
# 7 1-002984     1     3      0
```